# Как собрать Python скрипт для работы на других компьютерах в exe файл

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, exe, auto-py-to-exe

Не получается собрать exe файл. Пробовал **Nuitka** и **PyInstaller**. На компьютере где происходила сборка, всё запускается и работает в двух вариантах, а на другом, где нет Python - программа вылетает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать `pyinstaller` или же `nuitka` для компиляции py в exe. Почитайте документацию в интернете для этих модулей.

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что выглядит так, как будто я не пробовал и ничего не делал, просто ранее я собирал pyinstaller`om но последнее время, у меня скрипты не работаю на других компьютерах (после того, как переписал баг-трекинг и сделал его на библиотеке pandas)

Comment: К сожалению не помогло, при запуске на другом компьютере скрипт собранный nuitka вылетает, точно также как собранный pyinstaller`om, но при этом на компьютере на котором собирали всё работает.

Comment: Скорее всего это из за того что в случаи nuitka на другом компьютере не установлен пакет cpp от microsoft, либо из за того что там не включён модуль который вы используете в файле, вы можете исправить это добавив к комамнде утановки следующую строку `--include-module=MODULE` где вместо MODULE, Вы подставляете название модуля который используеться в скрипте. В случаи с pyinstaller проблема так же может быть из за отсутсвия модуля, здесь эта проблема решаеться добавлением этой строки `--collect-all MODULE` где также вместо MODULE Вы подставляете название модуля

Comment: Это не ответ, а бессодержательный комментарий на некачественный вопрос.  _Пробовал nuitka и  pyinstaller, не работает_ -- _Так попробуйте nuitka и  pyinstaller, и читайте документацию!_ Вечный цикл!

Comment: Я понимаю что ответ может показаться не корректынм, но прошу заметить что я его дал до того как вопрос был изменён, до этого там не было указано что пользователь использовал какуето библеотеку и не были укзаны точные проблемы. Я просто подсказал что можно использовать в данной ситуации, да признаю может не прав что не расписаль конкретоно про флаги или чтото подобное, но всё же цель форума подсказать, помочь, натолкнуть на мысль, а не сделать всё за человека, что это за медвежая услуга..